# Javascript server side file browser/manager

Tags: javascript, file-manager

I am using openCart for a project that I am putting together and am trying to figure out what jquery tool they are using for their image manager.  I couldn't find a reference to it in their forums and thought that perhaps one of you might know what it is.  Opening the image viewer brings up this window:

http://img.skitch.com/20100914-m6uxmwq7bshmq855jdw1yum5ma.jpg

where you can then explore the image folders contents and/or upload, rename, delete, etc images.  Double clicking on any of the files sets the relative path and closes the window.

I am curious as there is another project that I am working on where I would like to use something like this to manage images.

Any suggestions as to the name of this project or that of any other with similar functionality would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a classic, custom-developed, [**jQuery UI**](http://jqueryui.com/) window.

Comment: That's the bordering, but that says nothing of the image picker.